# Firebase - update data in Android by console

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to develop application by Firebase. 
I would like to make some listView with data. It's like a news app with actualization of specific data in listView.

For example: I would like to add Surname in listView by console.
It means when users download this app, and see some Surnames, I would like to add more Surnames by console.
Does somebody know how to achieve this in Firebase?

Is it even possible to update this by console in Firebase without update of application??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add values manually to the Database using the Firebase Console. Create a new child by adding **/child_name** to the database address (https://your-project.firebaseio.com/child_name). Then add new fields simply by hitting the **+** button.